# JQuery Autocomplete with tips inside the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want to create a search field with dropdown URL and tips like this:

[image: dropdown field]

I created an autocomplete form, but can't understand how to make tips on the right side.
My code:

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myForm" >
  <div class="search">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Input..." required id="autocomplete">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" >
  </div>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var availableUrls = [
    "https://google.com",
    "stack.com",
    "google.com"
  ];
  $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: availableUrls
  });
});
```

Please, help me to understand how to create tips in the dropdown field, how to create the part of tip, that is marked red:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661927/autocomplete-and-tooltip-with-jquery

Comment: @Oluwafemi I saw this answer on question, but it's not exactly that I need. I can't understand, how to create in one field autocomplete with tips on the  right side

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example to show the working of autocomplete. Hope it helps.

```js
$(function() {
  //the the autocomplete matches the word and gives us the related options
  var availableUrls = [
    
    "a",
    "ab",
    "abc",
    "abcd",
    "abcde"
  ];
  $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: availableUrls
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" >
  <div class="search">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Input..." required id="autocomplete">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" >
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ This is another autocomplete simple example.

Another Example showing how to display options in autocomplete
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: it's not exactly that i need, I can't understand, how to make tips in the right side of my autocomplete. I change my question, where I marked red, that I can't create.